# Upgrading kubuntu: error trying to overwrite package

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I am trying to pgrade my kubuntu to the latest version.

When running sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, I get:

```
(Reading database ... 558588 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg-progs_1%3a9b-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg-progs (1:9b-1) over (8c-2ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-progs_1%3a9b-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/rdjpgcom', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo-progs 1.3.0-0ubuntu2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-progs_1%3a9b-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So now I figured let's just remove that package:

```
sudo apt-get remove libjpeg-progs
sudo apt-get purge libjpeg-progs
```

But both commands also output:

```
(Reading database ... 558588 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg-progs_1%3a9b-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg-progs (1:9b-1) over (8c-2ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-progs_1%3a9b-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/rdjpgcom', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo-progs 1.3.0-0ubuntu2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-progs_1%3a9b-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I get apt to upgrade or remove this package?

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get install -f` ? if  so and it failed what is the output?

Comment: That runs error free. Doing a dist-upgrade after that still has the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some research and here is something you can try

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-progs_1%3a9b-1_amd64.deb
```

Then after run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to see if there are any errors